# What's wrong with this bit of python code using lambda?

Tags: python

Some python code that keeps throwing up an invalid syntax error:

```
stat.sort(lambda x1, y1: 1 if x1.created_at < y1.created_at else -1)
```

Comment: Belongs the missing ")" to the problem or is it a typo?

Comment: Can you revert it to the original, wrong version? Otherwise it is confusing.

Comment: You should accept one of the answers that were useful ;) ;) ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a better solution:

```
stat.sort(key=lambda x: x.created_at, reverse=True)
```

Or, to avoid the lambda altogether:

```
from operator import attrgetter
stat.sort(key=attrgetter('created_at'), reverse=True)
```

Comment: +1, that's more readable than my answer, and apparently faster: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-mutable.

Comment: Just added reverse=True to match the original requirement.

Comment: operator.attrgetter() is definitely an improvement, pythonically speaking.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [and-or trick](http://www.diveintopython.org/power_of_introspection/and_or.html):

```
lambda x1, y1: x1.created_at < y1.created_at and 1 or -1
```

Comment: The and-or hack is ugly and not necessary anymore.  Conditional expressions were introduced precisely to avoid it.